# difference between system.err.println and just throwing an exception? (java)

Tags: java, io, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to open and read a file passed from the command line.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        if ( (args[0].length() == 0) || (args[0] == null) || (args[0].isEmpty()) ) {
            System.err.println("Usage Error: No file name was provided.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        File file = new File(args[0]);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.err.println("Usage Error: The file, " + args[0] + ", does not exist.");
        }

        if (!file.canRead()) {
            System.err.println("Usage Error: The file, " + args[0] + ", cannot be read.");
        }
    } // main
}
```

I am not entirely sure how I should be handling file not found exceptions. My teacher has mentioned try/catch blocks but I wasn't sure if I needed those here. Is it sufficient to just test to see if the file was passed as an argument and if it wasn't use the System.err.print() method to give the user an error?

Also, if System.err.print() is called does it exit the program after that (meaning, do I need to include System.exit(1) after that)? Or is it better (in terms of design) to just do something like this:

```
public void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    // try to open file here
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {
       readFile(); 
   } catch (Exception e) {
       // exception handled here
   }
}
```

I just need to make sure the user actually passes a string as the file name and that it exists/can be read.

Comment: The difference is that they are not the same. One prints output to the console. The other changes the program flow. This is all documented. There  is no need to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions make it easier to deal with errors programmatically.

Meaning: when your program only consists of a main function, and you want to tell the user about "a file is not there"; then it doesn't make too much of a difference, if your program prints a reasonable message to stderr; and then exists with some non-zero return code; or if you throw an exception.

To the contrary; in your simple example; having **one** precise error message is actually to be preferred over throwing an exception and having the JVM print a (potentially confusing) stack trace to the user.

**But**: your current program is just a small example thing. As soon as things grow bigger, your program consists of calls to many different classes in different components. And then printing to stderr isn't a good idea any more. Then you want to make sure that one layer that runs into a problem has a defined way to communicate this situation; and that is what exceptions are meant for. In such situations, you very much prefer exceptions; because some higher layer can catch them - to then decide what to do. For example the program could decide to show the error message on some UI panel; or to put a message into a log file; or to send a text message to some mobile phone. All of that would be close to impossible, if you only printed to stderr.

Answer (score 0):

In `catch` instead `// exception handled here` you can write any code you want.
If you just throwing exception - java itself doing some standart things.

Answer (score 0):

Take your time and read Effective Java (2nd Edition) book form Joshua Bloch. 
Item 57 (Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions) in chapter Exceptions will clarify everything in this topic.